# How can I use one image as a texture for an entire model?

Tags: image, uv, texturing

I have this texture file:

[image: textures]

I want to apply this texture to these cubes (which I have joined together to be one object):

[image: cubes]

How do I apply one of each of the four textures to each of the cubes?

Comment: @Gwenn This question is specifically a UV texturing question, which IS directly related to Blender. Combining textures into one image is good practice for exporting models to be used with OpenGL or other 3D platforms.

Comment: Note that you can use the same image for different objects. There's no need to join them into one. Just make sure you UV unwrap each object and make sure you assign the image to the active uv layer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because these objects are merged into one, you have to [UV unwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/introduction.html#workflow) the object (the standard projection modes won't work) select the image from the drop down and position the UV's where you want them:

[image]

Comment: Actually you could project the cube, but you will still have to scale and position it.

Comment: Specifically, in edit mode: **A** to select all, **U** > **Reset** to overlap all faces. Then, **A** to deselect, and one at a time, hover a cube and press **L**. In the UV editor, scale to 0.5 and translate +/- 64 on X and Y axes to the desired positions.